# Autoload PSR-4 Specific Class

Tags: php, slim, psr-4

I have autoload setup via PSR-4 which works perfectly fine. However I want to be able to add a specific class on top of that, that I can access from anywhere in the application.

This is what I have currently:

```
    "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app"
         }
     }
```

However I want to add a class called 'Redis' which is located in app/Lib/Redis.php so that from any Controller I can call Redis::method(); without having to add 'use App\Lib\Redis;' to the top of each file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Even if this were possible, it would defeat the entire purpose of namespacing your classes in the first place. Learn to love `use` statements, and depend on interfaces, not implementations.

Comment: And you want to do this only using what autoloading offers? I mean, do you also want to add some code (like new classes) to current code, to achieve what you want? If yes, you should know this is possible. Read about facade design pattern, it gives you and idea (or even a solution). And for a real world example, have a look at Laravel source code to see how they implement facades and specially how they alias them to be accessed without any namespace.

Comment: This [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/) is a bit old but seems to explain Laravel mechanism in quite detail.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done directly.

You could create a global function redis() and register than with composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app"
    },
    "files"" {
        "app/functions.php",
    }
}
```

If this `redis()` function returned an instance of your `Redis` class, then I think that you could then do:

```
redis()->method();
```

Whether you should do this or not is another matter - unit testing becomes *highly problematic*. Personally, I would have a use statement and inject an instance of the `Redis` object into the constructors of the classes that need it.